# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field (Spring Boot v 1.5.1)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am newbie in spring boot and mongoDB please help.

I am getting unsatified dependcy expressed through mongoTemplate, I am unable to find the root cause of it. Below is the stack trace of it.

```
"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gmailPullHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gmailPullService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gmailPullService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gmailMailDataRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gmailMailDataRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.plash.configurator.Application.main(Application.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Since there are three unsatisfied dependency which one is causing error, i am unable to find it.

**NOTE:**  gmailMailDataRepository class is extended by MongoRepository, GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom

gmailMailDataRepository :

```
@Repository
public interface GmailMailDataRepository extends MongoRepository<GmailMailData, String>, GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom {


   {'threadidslist.threadid':?1}{'useremail':?2}")
    List<GmailMailData> getListByThreadidmMsgidEmailid(String messagid, String threadid, String useremail);


    void saveObjectToMsgList(GmailMessages gm, String useremailid, String threadid, String prospectemailid);


}
```

Below is GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom and GmailMailDataRepositoryImpl:

GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom:

```
    public interface GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom {

    void saveObjectToMsgList(GmailMessages g, String useremailid, String threadid, String prospectemailid);
}
```

GmailMailDataRepositoryImpl:

```
public class GmailMailDataRepositoryImpl implements GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom {
// private final MongoOperations operations;


@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


Update update = new Update();

@Override
public void saveObjectToMsgList(GmailMessages gm, String useremailid, String threadid, String prospectemailid) {

    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("useremail").is(useremailid).and("prospectemailid").is(prospectemailid).and("threadidslist.threadid").is(threadid));
    update.push("threadidslist.$.messagelist", gm);
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, GmailMailData.class);

}
```

Application.properities configuration for mongo is as following:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.password=#########
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

build.gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
```

Comment: Problem seems to be injecting `pullhandler` named variable into `pullshandlerservice`. Can you add those classes to the post ?

Comment: The root cause actually seems to be a `StackOverflowError` in the init method of `MongoDataAutoConfiguration`. Perhaps taking a look at the sources of this class reveals some more insights?!

Comment: @dpr I have not explicitally Configured mongo properties, everything lies under application.class where EnableAutoConfiguration is already there.

Comment: @Veeram I tried commenting pullshandlerservice, but now error is promting where ever that GmailMailDataRepository  is used

Comment: The  auto wiring is not working correctly.  Make sure your classes are defined in packages where spring is scanning them.

Comment: @Veeram I re-checked its on place.

Comment: Why do you define `void saveObjectToMsgList(GmailMessages gm, String useremailid, String threadid, String prospectemailid);`in `GmailMailDataRepository` when it is already in `GmailMailDataRepositoryCustom` (which is extended by `GmailMailDataRepository`)? Remove it from `GmailMailDataRepository`

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Thanks for correcting me. Anyways I solved the error it was in modelclass.

Comment: Maybe you could add your fix as answer to your own question? This might help people that encounter the same problem as you did, as the fix doesn't seem to be too obvious...

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved. It was model level error.

List casting was wrong.

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "GmailOtherMailData")
public class GmailOtherMailData {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String useremail;
    private List<GmailOtherThreads> threadidslist;

}
```

I supposed to cast GmailOtherThreads object in List but i was using some other object. Because of wrong casting i was getting error everywhere in code.